# Is it possible to deprcate a method from superclass in child class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a superclass like this:

```
public abstract class Foo {

    //some method here    

    public void aMethod() {
        //some code
    }
}
```

and a 2 child-classes `BarOne` and `BarTwo` which extends `Foo` class.

In `BarOne`, everything are normal, but in `BarTwo`, I want to `@Deprecated` `aMethod()`

To be precise: I mean hiding it, not deprecate, due to privacy reasons. Are there some better way rather than override the method?

Comment: "I want to @Deprecated aMethod() due to privacy purposes" can you please explain? How can you achieve privacy by deprecating a method?

Comment: If you have aMethod() that is deprecated in one of two child classes, why not move it to BarOne class instead? Foo is abstract any way.

Comment: @AmitBera I mean I want to hide it :(( fixed the post

Comment: @Beri But if I had 20 classes which half of them use the `aMethod()` but  the others half don't use. I think copy-paste is not a good choice.

Comment: What do you mean by "privacy"? Any subtype has to provide the entire public contract of its supertype.

Comment: @HaiVuQuang but your example said that you needed only 2. If you have more, then. maybe use an interface, and produce your class through a factory method, that returns an interface that is implemented by your BarTwo, but has no aMethod. There are many possibilities, but as GhostCat mentioned - first think if you have the right model.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Comment: @GhostCat cuz you made me redesign a better model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even when it is *technically* possible, it conceptually wrong. As it is a **conceptual** violation of the Liskov substitution principle.

You see, inheritance is more than putting `A extends B` in your source code. The idea is that the methods in your base class define a contract. Code using these methods should not need to **care** about the fact that such a method is implemented in the base class - or overridden in a subclass.

You are basically saying: I want to have method `x()` on the base class, but I want to express that `x()` is deprecated on child classes. Which would mean that code calling `x()` should only do that if it is calling the method on a base class instance.

Thus the non-answer here is: don't even think about doing things like that. Either a method is "fine to be called" on all levels of inheritance, or it is not. There is no point of putting such a restriction on child classes only.

So the real answer here: step back, and consider *why* you came up with this idea. Then look out for *other* ways to solve that problem.

And given the comment about *hiding* it: same story. And technically: you can't **hide** a method. Because, as said when calling `foo.bar()` is a valid statement for some base class `foo` instance - then it needs to be a valid statement also when `foo` happens to be an instance of a subclass.

The only thing that is legit:

- have javadoc on the **base** method explaining that subclasses might override methods to do nothing (or throw up an exception)
- then, well, have your sub class methods do whatever is required

Comment: I got it. But I mean, I wanna hide it, not deprecate it, sorry for my bad english :(( Just fixed the post a moment ago :((

Comment: It isn't *necessarily* a violation of LSP. For example, Collection classes have optional methods, which are documented to throw UnsupportedOperationException if they are "absent". So, provided it is documented in your superclass that it may be unsafe to invoke the method (which is a *horrible* design... however), you can make the subclass method do something to make the code blow up if invoked.

Comment: @AndyTurner True. When the contract says "you dont have a contract", then well, you dont have a contract.

Comment: @AndyTurner The very idea of an unsupported operation is arguably a violation of LSP, at least in spirit. The existence of a method should imply it's supported. Sure, you could add a disclaimer to any method saying "subclasses may or may not do something entirely different or nothing at all" and escape the LSP police, but you're still breaking the OOP paradigm of programming to an interface.

Answer (score 6):

You are describing something like this:

```
            ___________
           | class Foo |
           |           |
           | aMethod() |
           |___________|
            /         \
           /           \
 _________/____       __\___________
| class BarOne |     | class BarTwo |
|              |     |              |
|  inherits    |     |  hides       |
|  aMethod()   |     |  aMethod()   |
|______________|     |______________|
```

You cannot and you should not do that, as already described in GhostCats answer.

However, what you can do is something like this:

```
            ___________
           | class Baz |
           |           |
           |___________|
            /         \
           /           \
 _________/____       __\___________
| class Foo    |     | class BarTwo |
|              |     |              |
|  aMethod()   |     |______________|
|______________|
       |
       |
 ______|_______
| class BarOne |
|              | 
|  inherits    |
|  aMethod()   |
|______________|
```

`Baz` would then have all the code that `Foo` previously had, except `aMethod()`. `Foo` would simply add `aMethod()` and be the *superclass* for all *classes* that want to inherit `aMethod()`, while `Baz` is the *superclass* for all *classes* that don't want to inherit `aMethod()`.

Comment: Nice one, especially with that cute ascii art. are you drawing these manually?

Comment: Yes, I typed those by hand in notepad xD

Comment: @MaxVollmer thanks a lot! Just upvoted your ASCII art XD. I've redesigned the model and added some interface thanks to your suggestion!